# How to break links from activesheet and replace formulas pointing to other sheets with values?

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to do two things with one macro:
1) Break external links.
2) Change formulas parts pointing to other sheets to values.

I can find macros to break external links, there are a few methods to do that, but I have a great issue with the second point.

For example - if I have such formula in my active worksheet:
"=K6*34+Sheet1!A1"

I would like it to be replaced by this:
"=K6*34+25"

So, Sheet1!A1 reference should be replaced with its underlying value.

I cannot provide any sort of half-decently reliable code. I cannot find anything on the web either, as everything relates to breaking links and things on a workbook level, not a worksheet.

Why do I need this? I want to "break" one of the worksheets in the workbook and send it via mail. I can do every part of the macro except reliably finding and replacing references with values.

Comment: There is a [replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) function.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't simple calculate all the formulas? The easiest way this could work is to copy the entire sheet/used range then paste values. If you want to keep the formulas for future use, simple duplicate the current sheet and paste values in your new sheet

Comment: I need to have the formulas working. The idea is to save a worksheet with all formulas and everything in it working, replacing external references with values. Therefore, I cannot simply paste whole worksheet as values, as it would "destroy" the whole new worksheet. What I want to do is to simply replace the references with values, but I can't figure out how to do it.

@Warcupine I have been thinking about this function, but I can't find a way to reliably change the "external reference" part. I think this is a question of text functions but I can't make it work.

Comment: by external, are they in a separate workbook, or the same workbook, but a different sheet?

Comment: Parsing formulas is a non-trivial task normally - good luck!

Comment: @el_oso those references are in the same workbook. They reference values in the same workbook but on a different sheets. What I am looking for is to replace them with values in referenced cells, so I can send this one sheet without "breaking it".

Also, the rest of the formula needs to stay the same, so only the "reference" needs to be replaced with value, no the whole formula. I can't paste as value the whole cell for example, I need to replace that one little thing :(

Comment: You may need regexes to find the various references, though depending on how inconsistent the sheets are (between macro executions) it may, honestly, not be worth the effort. As BigBen said it will become non-trivial very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you should define a load of names for cells that 'export' a value off a sheet.  Then when you want to breakaway then you loop through the names and replace with a constant.

So this way you won't need to parse the formulae which (as has been pointed out) would be very difficult.

[image]

Comment: Apologies but I do not understand it fully. What kind of names? Could you try to elaborate a bit further please, so a stupid person like me can actually understand? :)

Comment: I have added screenshot of where to find the names on the Excel ribbon interface.

Comment: Switch on the macro recorder to see VBA equivalent.